# Good way to structure a SDL project

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl2

I am absolutely new to c++ and am trying to learn SDL2 with c++. I am setting up my first project and I was unsure if the way I have structured the project is good or if I have over done it. Here is the code:

`generalFuncs.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL.h"
#include <iostream>

struct State
{
    bool quit = false;
};

class CreateWindow
{
public:
    CreateWindow(
        int x,
        int y,
        int w,
        int h,
        bool fullScreen = false
    )
    {
        pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", x, y, w, h, fullScreen);
    }

    inline SDL_Window* getWindow()
    {
        return pWindow;
    }
private:
    SDL_Window* pWindow;
};


class Events
{
public:
    void handleEvents(State* state)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                state->quit = true;
        }
    }

private:
    SDL_Event event;
};
```

`renderer.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "SDL.h"

class Renderer
{
public:
    Renderer(SDL_Window* pWindow)
    {
        pRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pWindow, -1, 0);
    }

    inline SDL_Renderer* getRenderer()
    {
        return pRenderer;
    }

    inline void clearScreen(int r, int g, int b, int a)
    {
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(pRenderer, r, g, b, a);
        SDL_RenderClear(pRenderer);
    }

    inline void update()
    {
        SDL_RenderPresent(pRenderer);
    }

    void render()
    {
        
    }

private:
    SDL_Renderer* pRenderer;
};
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <vector>
#include "generalFuncs.h"
#include "renderer.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not initialze SDL properly \n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    CreateWindow window(SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1200, 600);
    Renderer renderer(window.getWindow());
    State state;
    Events events;

    if (window.getWindow() == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not window properly \n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    if (renderer.getRenderer() == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Could not window properly \n" << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    while (!state.quit)
    {
        events.handleEvents(&state);
        renderer.clearScreen(255, 255, 255, 255);
        renderer.render();
        renderer.update();
    }

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window.getWindow());
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
```

The way I plan on using this is make other header files, include them to `render.h`, then draw them in the `render` method. Please let me know if there are better way to do things or if my setup can be improved. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that yes, the code can be structured somewhat better.

First of all, I'd tend to "RAII all the things". Code like this at the end of `main` makes me extremely suspicious:

```cpp
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window.getWindow());
    SDL_Quit();
```

I'd *strongly* prefer that those be handled in the destructor of some object so they happen automatically.

So, I'd rename `CreateWindow` to just `Window`. Then I'd add a destructor that called `SDL_DestroyWindow`, so it'll automatically clean itself up when it goes out of scope.

```cpp
class Window {
public:
    Window(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool fullScreen = false) {
        pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", x, y, w, h, fullScreen);
        if (pWindow == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create window");
    }

    ~Window() { SDL_DestroyWindow(pWindow); }

    operator SDL_Window*() { return pWindow; }

private:
    SDL_Window *pWindow;
};
```

Likewise I'd add an `Application` class (or something on that order that calls `SDL_Init` in its ctor, and `SDL_Quit();` in its dtor, so simply defining a variable of that type automatically initializes SDL, and cleans up before it goes out of scope.

```cpp
class Application {
public:    
    Application() { 
        if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
        {
            std::stringstream buffer;
            buffer << "Could not intialize SDL properly: " << SDL_GetError();

            throw std::runtime_error(buffer.str());
        }        
    }

    ~Application() {
        SDL_Quit();
    }
};
```

...and of course, Renderer should clean up after itself as well:

```cpp
    ~Renderer() { 
        SDL_DestroyRenderer(pRenderer);
    }
```

I'd also add definitions of copy assignment, move assignment, copy construction, and move construction to `Renderer`, `Window` and `Application`, so somebody won't accidentally do something nasty and breaking with them. In this case, they're probably move-only classes, so we'd do something on this order:

```cpp
    Renderer(Renderer const &) = delete;
    Renderer(Renderer &&other) { 
        pRenderer = other.pRenderer; 
        other.pRenderer = nullptr; 
    }
    Renderer &operator=(Renderer const &) = delete;
    Renderer &operator=(Renderer && other) { 
        pRenderer = other.pRenderer; 
        other.pRenderer = nullptr; 
        return *this;
    }
```

Window would probably be similar in this regard, and Application should probably delete all of them.

I'd also have each of the classes report problems with construction by throwing an exception, rather than leaving it to client code to detect the problem when (for example) it has failed to create a window.

```cpp
    Window(int x, int y, int w, int h, bool fullScreen = false) {
        pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("", x, y, w, h, fullScreen);
        if (pWindow == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to create window");
    }
}
```

Rather than `Events::handleEvents` being passed a Boolean in a structure, I'd have it just return a value to indicate when the program should exit:

```cpp
    bool handleEvents()
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

I'd also put all of these in a namespace named something like `sdl` (or `sdl2`, or something on that order).

With that "stuff" in place, our `main` can shrink to something on this order:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    try {
        sdl::Application app;

        sdl::Window window(SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 1600, 1200);
        sdl::Renderer renderer(window);
        sdl::Events events;

        while (events.handleEvents())
        {
            renderer.clearScreen(255, 255, 255, 255);
            renderer.render();
            renderer.update();
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception const &e) { 
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Although I haven't shown it above, I'd at least be *tempted* to require that a reference to an `sdl::Application` be passed to the ctor when you create an `sdl::Window` object. This assures that you've created an `sdl::Application` object first, thereby assuring that SDL is initialized before you try to create a window with it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Appreciate it. I have one more question: What is the point of "copy assignment, move assignment, copy construction, and move construction". Pardon my  ignorance, I am new.

Comment: Is `operator SDL_Window*() { return pWindow; }` operator overloading ? In tutorials I have only seen overloading with ints and other builtin data structures.